# How would you find text in a string in python and then look for a number after it?

Tags: python, string, search

I have a log file and at the end of each line in the file there is this string:
`Line:#` where `#` is the line number.

I am trying to get the # and compare it to the previous line's number. what would be the best way to do that in python?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare"? What output are you looking for?

Comment: Each line is numbered and I am trying to see if there were any skipped lines in the log. So if they differ by more than one. I know how I would do this in C++ but not in python

Comment: I know you're looking for the best way, but is there anything that you tried?

Comment: Nothing that worked. I am pretty new with python so I don't know where to start. I can find the string "Line:" but i don't know how to find the number after it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you don't have something convenient to split a string on, meaning a regular expression might make more sense. That is, if the lines in your log file are structured like:

```
date: 1-15-2013, error: mildly_annoying, line: 121
date: 1-16-2013, error: err_something_bad, line: 123
```

Then you won't be able to use `line.split('#')` as mgilson as suggested, although if there is always a colon, `line.split(':')` might work. In any case, a regular expression solution would look like:

```
import re
numbers = []
for line in log:
    digit_match = re.search("(\d+)$", line)
    if digit_match is not None:
        numbers.append(int(digit_match.group(1)))
```

Here the expression `"(\d+)$"` is matching some number of digits and then the end of the line. We extract the digits with the `group(1)` method on the returned match object and then add them to our list of line numbers.

If you're not confident that the "Line: #" will always come at the end of the log, you could replace the regular expression used above with something akin to `"Line:\s*(\d+)"` which checks for the string "Line:" then some (or no) whitespace, and then any number of digits.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably use `str.split` because it seems easy:

```
with open('logfile.log') as fin:
    numbers = [ int(line.split(':')[-1]) for line in fin ]
```

Now you can use `zip` to compare one number with the next one:

```
for num1,num2 in zip(numbers,numbers[1:]):
    compare(num1,num2)  #do comparison here.
```

---

Of course, this isn't lazy (you store every line number in the file at once when you really only need 2 at a time), so it might take up a lot of memory if your files are *HUGE*.  It wouldn't be hard to make it lazy though:

```
def elem_with_next(iterable):
    ii = iter(iterable)
    prev = next(ii)
    for here in ii:
        yield prev,here
        prev = here

with open('logfile.log') as fin:
    numbers = ( int(line.split(':')[-1]) for line in fin )
    for num1,num2 in elem_with_next(numbers):
        compare(num1,num2)
```

Comment: a simple and reasonable solution, I use things like the first one a lot

Comment: @EmmettJ.Butler -- Yeah.  You could use `regex` or something like that, but I'm betting `str.split` is faster and easier to understand.

Comment: if it's a given that the lines will *always* end with this Line:# bit, it's indeed easier.

Comment: I think '#' is the actual number in his question.

Comment: @LWZ -- Thanks.  Updated -- All I needed to do was change `#` to `:` and I think it should work.